# Couldn't find a way to calculate, helps appreciated

Tags: excel-formula, powerpivot

i am really at a beginner level on powerpivot and currently trying to learn it by some experiments that i create with my data. yesterday i got stuck on something. [sample of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djeg3.png)

in basic terms i want to calculate ratio of the investment to the total fund values. for example investment type A's ratio for fund number one is 100/1500 and B's 200/1500. i want to do this for every fund which i have more than a hundred right now and for the every investment inside of them. it was easy to formulate it with sumifs in excel but i wanted to do it on powerpivot. couldnt find a way to do it with DAX formulas because i am quite new like i said. if there is a way to calculate it i would be so happy if you share with me

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used DAX but can proffer some steer/direction RE resolving:  try something along the lines of "DIVIDE(FILTER(ALL( Value ), Value[Fund Number] = 1), SUM (FILTER (ALL( Value) , Value[Fund Number] = 1) ))" for value 1 (complete guestimate - I've referred to this source as a means of guidance - and am not proposing a formal solution given this area is completely new to me - hopefully someone else far more adept comes to the rescue if not consider this a 'backup' remedy to attempt as last resort! : http://www.excelhelp.info/dax-for-calculating-ratios/ )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.